# Counting no. of way 2 people who do not own a dog, and at least 2 people who don't own a cat given the info. below.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> 100 people have come to the annual pet owner's meeting. A quick show
>   of hands demonstrates that 60 people own cats and 55 own dogs. Give
>   the numerical answer and a brief explanation for the following
>   question:
>
> How many people must be randomly selected for a committee to guarantee at least 2 people who don't own a dog, and at least 2 people
>   who don't own a cat?

Is it $62$ ?

$60$ cats + $2$ dogs ?

Comment: Your answer is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the right answer.
You need to guarantee that at least two dog owners are chosen, thus, the worst case scenario is where you pick them all cat owners.

The generalization, where
$$n = \text{Number of cat owners}$$
$$m= \text{Number of dog owners}$$
$$i= \text{minimum dog owners chosen, } i>0$$
$$j= \text{minimum cat owners chosen, } j>0$$ 
is

$n+j$  if  $m<n$

or
$m+i$ if $n<m$.